# How can I individually validate the selected option in multiple RadioGroups within a ListView?

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to Android dev and programming in general. My goal is to create a quiz in this [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxXd8.png).

Each row is a custom view that includes a RadioGroup with 3 RadioButtons. And that is working fine, as you can see in the picture.

This is how the List is being populated:

```
private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<QuizQuestion> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.questionsListView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<QuizQuestion> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(ShortQuiz.this, R.layout.item_view, myQuestions);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        }

        QuizQuestion currentQuestion = myQuestions.get(position);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
        imageView.setImageResource(currentQuestion.getImageId());

        //Question
        TextView question = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_question);
        question.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());

        //Game
        TextView game = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_game);
        game.setText(currentQuestion.getGameName());

        //Option A
        TextView optionA = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_radioA);
        optionA.setText(currentQuestion.getOptionA());

        //Option B
        TextView optionB = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_radioB);
        optionB.setText(currentQuestion.getOptionB());

        //Option C
        TextView optionC = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_radioC);
        optionC.setText(currentQuestion.getOptionC());


        return itemView;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to 'access' (set/get ids) each RadioGroup after creation in order to validate for right or wrong answers, which I want to do in one go pressing a button, as in: If the selected option is correct then +1 to Correct Answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewHolder for each row.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html

You can reference the items in each individual row.  You can search for examples for how the ViewHolder is used in practice, but in general each row in the holder will be stored with a setTag() and retreived with a getTag().  So you can obtain the items in a view like:

```
view.getTag();
```